# jQuery datatables grouping return values

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I need to display values on a table which are grouped. Currently I do it manually via two SQL scripts.

Instead of applying these scripts into my dao, can I do it client-side somehow?

Table contents would look like this

```
fruit name, fruit bought, fruit sold
apple,        1, 0        
apple,        0, 1
orange,       1, 0
orange,       1, 0
```

Desired result on html table would be.

```
Fruit name - Fruit bought - Fruits not bought
apples    -   9           -        20
oranges   -  10           -        10
```

I'm currently using jQuery with datatables.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to do this at the database level to begin with:

```
SELECT fruitname, SUM(fruit_bought), SUM(fruit_sold)
FROM table
GROUP BY fruitname
ORDER BY fruitname
```

Of course, you'd need somewhere to get the original inventory level to calculate your "not sold" value, but this query would give you the sum of the bought/sold values.

Comment: Hi i wish it could be that simple but, im actually sorting by fruitname, now for each fruit name there are 4 scenarios that i need to provide a count for. At the moment my script is outputting 4 types of scenarios into a temp file, then i run another script to put them in one row groupped by fruit name. i'm using an informix db aswell so it doesn't help with the scripting.